# SpriteKit how to handle multiple collision detection

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, swift4

I am trying to create a flappy bird clone. I have created physics bodies for the ground, the bird and both of the pipes.

I want to make the bird to not go through the ground but be able to go through the pipes. I am using the following code to achieve this.

```
// Collisions

        // Bird
        bird.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = birdCategory
        bird.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = groundCategory
        bird.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory | pipeCategory

        // Ground
        ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
        ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = birdCategory

        // Pipes
        pipe1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = pipeCategory
        pipe1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

        pipe2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = pipeCategory
        pipe2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
```

The problem is that the bird interacts with the pipes and the ground even though I set `pipe1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask` and `pipe2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask` to be equal to 0.

I searched a bit about it and according to Apple's documentation:

> When two physics bodies contact each other, a collision may occur. This body’s collision mask is compared to the other body’s category mask by performing a logical AND operation. If the result is a nonzero value, this body is affected by the collision.

I am not really sure why the bird does not clip through the pipe when it clearly should.

**EDIT1**

I have defined the category bit masks in the first section of my code like so:

```
let birdCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let groundCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let pipeCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
```

**EDIT2**

This is how I defined the physics bodies for all the nodes:

Bird:

```
bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:birdTexture.size().height / 2)
bird.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false 
// The bird is dynamic later on the touchesBgan function
```

Ground:

```
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width:self.frame.width, height: 1))
ground.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
```

Pipe(s)

```
pipe1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: pipe1Texture.size())
pipe1.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
```

Comment: Show the definition of your bit masks.

Comment: @ElTomato If I get what you saying correctly I edited my question above.

Comment: The definition of your bit masks is invalid.

Comment: @ElTomato I haven't really used SpriteKit before. It would be very helpful if you could show me how it is the correct way of defining bit masks.

Comment: @ApostolosPezodromouApope Can you show how you define your physics bodies?

Comment: @SteveIves Edited the post. Hope this info will suffice.